# File descriptor limit on CentOS 7

Tags: systemd, ulimit

I am having hard time understanding resource limits (ulimit) with systemd. As I understand it, systemd brings some additional complexities to setting file descriptor limit.

/etc/security/limits.d/99-name.conf

```
couchbase hard nofile 100000
couchbase soft nofile 100000
```

/etc/systemd/system/[SERVICE_NAME].service.d/limits.conf

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=100000
```

I found [this](https://ma.ttias.be/increase-open-files-limit-in-mariadb-on-centos-7-with-systemd/) and [this](https://sskaje.me/systemd-ulimit/), but it rises more questions than answers.

- Which of the above is correct and why (or is there some other way, or should I set both)?
- Can I use `ulimit` command?
- How do I verify that the limit is really set for a daemon?
- What about daemons, which relies on `ulimit`?

Comment: The systemd service drop-in should be working.

Comment: @MichaelHampton So the "/etc/security/limits.d/" way is now deprecated?

Comment: I don't remember if it's deprecated or not, but I certainly don't use it anymore.